# Delete extra toolbar on top of the screen in GNOME fallback mode?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome, nautilus

Clean install to 11.10, trying to keep Gnome Classic.

I've installed gnome-session-fallback and removed unity via software center, and this toolbar still won't go away.

[image]

Has anyone had any problems like this trying to keep Classic

Comment: I believe that's the global application meny toolbar, try: sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu

Comment: It isn't. It's just the menubar in Nautilus.

Comment: @borg - see similar question http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Comment: I believe Jo-Erlend Schinstad is correct and it is the nautilus menubar. I disabled it using gnome-tweak-tool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to install GNOME Tweak Tool (*gnome-tweak-tool*) and go to "Desktop" and then change the "Have file manager handle desktop" to off.

To install gnome-tweak-tool in Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem with this is that if you turn off the setting you suggest, then you can't have icons on the desktop anymore.
I think what is hoped for is that the menu goes away, but that icons can be seen and manipulated on the desktop as usual.

Answer (score 2):

The gnome-tweak-tool solution turns off everything put on the desktop like linked folders and files, which is unacceptable for me. I use the desktop as part of my work space.

That extra toolbar (Global Menubar) is part of the Unity desktop. Remove Unity and the toolbar is gone. [This article](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.html) shows you how to remove all aspects of the Unity.

Here are the relevant command from that article to solve this problem:

- Remove the appmenu. The appmenu (or Global Menubar) is that function that brings up the menu 'panel. Since we are going to remove unity, becomes useless (and also a problem because there would appear under the menu panel nautilus gnome)

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt indicator-appmenu
  ```
- To remove more Unity parts:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications unity-greeter unity-common unity-asset-pool unity-2d-launcher unity-2d libunity-misc4 libunity-2d-private0 gir1.2-unity-4.0
  ```